# Error "Could not connect to MySQLserver" in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

Every time I start MAMP and open the start page I get error can't connect to mysql. I'm not sure what I've done but I think I've reset the password and have now forgotten what I changed it too!

I've tried to change it in terminal however I just get: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

How can I fix this?

I have thought about just doing a new install on MAMP however I have a number of sites in my htdocs and don't want to lose them.

Here is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: @mellamokb Your link isn't related to MAMP

Comment: @soyuka: Correct, I am not familiar with MAMP and didn't realize there was a built-in option.  So I upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you change the Mysql Root Password in MAMP ?

> Open MAMP => Server => Mysql => Change the root password (assuming
>   you've MAMP PRO 2.1.1)

You won't leave your websites if you copy the htdocs directory located under :

> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs (Assuming you're under OS X)

Comment: Hi thanks for you help. I just have MAMP not the MAMP PRO, can I still do this? Do I need to do this is terminal? sorry if thats a dumb question I'm still getting use to using mamp

Comment: Hmm in your GUI isn't there an option do do these ? I'll look further.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the old Mysql installed in the Pc and Run the web browser then the same error will come then refresh the page this will work